# Azure Service Bus Duplicate messages

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues, azure-sdk-.net

I have an application that sends messages in batches to the Azure Service Premium queue. I am noticing that if I am sending 1000 messages in total (20 batches with 50 messages each, per-message size is 10 KB), I am noticing an extra count of messages in the queue. The extra count varies for every run. There are strictly no other senders. Is there any reason why this could happen? Or, if my logic needs to be checked thoroughly? I just want to eliminate any reasons inherent to the operations of the Azure Service bus.

I am using Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus latest version in .net 4.8

Comment: When we activate duplication, the Windows Azure Service Bus will start to store a history of our messages. This period of time can be configured to range from only a few minutes to days. If a duplicate message is sent to the Service Bus, the service will automatically ignore the message.